# Hive map-reduce query is failing

Tags: mapreduce, hiveql, mapr

I am trying to run my first Hive query which can launches map-reduce job. I have followed all the steps given at "http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive".

"web_log" table has been crated and data loading completed with no error. 
But when trying to execute "SELECT web_log. FROM web_log WHERE web_log.url LIKE '%doc'*" I am getting following exception.

```
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator Starting Job = job_1429420954627_0002, 
Tracking URL = http://yarn-training:8088/proxy/application_1429420954627_0002/ 
Kill Command = /opt/mapr/bin/hadoop job -kill job_1429420954627_0002 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0 2015-04-19 00:19:15,690 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0% Ended Job = job_1429420954627_0002 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information... FAILED: 
Hi
```

Could someone guide me please.

Comment: Can you check your task tracker logs once and you may find detailed logs

Comment: Thanks Alekya, checked lot of log files under /hive directory, but not getting any updated log so far.  Could you please tell me some path or a directory name, I can search for it.

Comment: check your tracking URLonce. Tracking URL = http://yarn-training:8088/proxy/application_1429420954627_0002/

Answer (score 0):

You are having number of reducers = 0 as your job is map only job. And now is this your query  ?? I think your select statement has something missing.

```
SELECT web_log.* FROM web_log WHERE web_log.url LIKE '%doc';
```

Comment: Thanks Venkata, but I have used the same. No problem with my query.